# Which is the best plugin for membership based site in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for the best plugin for membership based site in the wordpress

I want following features:

1) For example, if i have 200 images in my site then some member have to right to see full images, some of them 100, some of them 50

2) Also, my images do not copied by anyone

Answer (score 2):

I'm using s2Members (https://s2member.com/) as there is a free option and pro option which is still fairly priced. It has many advantages and many many addons.
It's easily extendible also.  You can setup unlimited user roles and each user role can have different privileges just as you need it.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments!
As your suggestion, I install S2Members free version, but having problem in email notification.
I didn't receive any notification from new user and new user also not received any notification.

I also used wp mail smtp plugin but didn't receive any email.

Please Suggest

Answer (score 1):

If you are using woocommerce then you must use [WooCommerce Memberships - WooCommerce](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZvKOQ7tLRAhUWSY8KHdG7DXsQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwoocommerce.com%2Fproducts%2Fwoocommerce-memberships%2F&usg=AFQjCNFay-xCCa3dCOHchIiUPbgeJg1BkQ&sig2=qL_kvVVVyTcGG5T4dIYE_w&bvm=bv.144224172,d.c2I) plugin which considers best solution for membership programs.

You can also use subscriptions plugin along with the user groups plugin which provides subscription based on the groups.